# puppet not supported on windows 2012R2

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install puppet agent on windows 2012R2 (data Center edition)...but i get below error... looking at what is supported by puppet, i thought 2012R2 is supported, so why am i getting an error below stating puppet is NOT supported....

My master is running 3.6, so what do i need to do to get puppet working on 2012R2

```
Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/staging_h
ttp_get.rb
Info: Loading facts in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/var/lib/facter/windows.r
b
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: OS No
t supported by puppet module ssh at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/base/manifest
s/params.pp:5 on node puppetwin1.ec2.internal
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

C:\Users\Administrator>facter
architecture => x64
dir => C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\facter
domain => ec2.internal
env_windows_installdir => C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet
facterversion => 1.7.5
fqdn => puppetwin1.ec2.internal
hardwaremodel => x64
hostname => puppetwin1
id => puppetwin1\administrator
interfaces => Ethernet
ipaddress => 10.0.1.155
ipaddress_ethernet => 10.0.1.155
is_virtual => true
kernel => windows
kernelmajversion => 6.3
kernelrelease => 6.3.9600
kernelversion => 6.3.9600
macaddress => 12:86:09:3C:E4:27
macaddress_ethernet => 12:86:09:3C:E4:27
manufacturer => Xen
memoryfree => 3.18 GB
memoryfree_mb => 3256.10
memorysize => 4.00 GB
memorysize_mb => 4095.61
memorytotal => 4.00 GB
netmask => 255.255.255.0
netmask_ethernet => 255.255.255.0
network_ethernet => 10.0.1.0
operatingsystem => windows
operatingsystemrelease => 6.3.9600
osfamily => windows
path => C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\puppet\bin;C:\Program Files (x
86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\facter\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\hier
a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppe
t Labs\Puppet\sys\ruby\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\sys\tools\b
in;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\W
indowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files (
x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin
physicalprocessorcount => 1
processor0 => Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
processorcount => 1
productname => HVM domU
ps => tasklist.exe
puppetversion => 3.6.0
rubysitedir => C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/site_
ruby/1.9.1
rubyversion => 1.9.3
serialnumber => ec2377af-d1b0-1d96-afd6-05e536bd837f
timezone => Coordinated Universal Time
uptime => 0:27 hours
uptime_days => 0
uptime_hours => 0
uptime_seconds => 1636
virtual => xen

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Thanks for the note below about this not being an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This was my bad, I had a module on my master called **SSH** that spitted out that info and my site.pp had nothing by default section and when I ran puppet on this new windows machine I was getting that error...

**To fix** this, I changed my `site.pp` site definition...